# React component state change issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iterator

I am creating one react form which looks like wizard type means on click of next button, it will load another component.

To do with this, i am using javascript iterators. I am updating state based on what iterator returns but i dont understand its not updating state of the component.

**Code:**

```
console.clear();
var Email = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="control-label">Email:</label>
        <input className="form-control" />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Password = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="control-label">Password:</label>
        <input className="form-control" />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Contact = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="control-label">Contact:</label>
        <input className="form-control" />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Form = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    this.fit = this.flowIterator([<Email />,<Password />,<Contact />]);
    return {
        view: this.fit.next(),
      submitBtnText: "Next"
    };
  },
  flowIterator: function(array){
    var nextIndex = 0;    
    return {
       next: function(){
            console.log("nextIndex=",nextIndex);
            console.log("array.length-1=",array.length-1);
            console.log("nextIndex == array.length-1 =",nextIndex == array.length-1);
          return nextIndex == array.length-1 ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: true} :
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false};
       }
    }
  },
    onFormSubmit: function(e){
    this.setState({
      onChange: this.onStateChange()
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  onStateChange: function(){
    console.log("State change event fired!!");
    this.setState({
        view: this.fit.next(),
      submitBtnText: "Next"
    });
    console.log("this.state.view.done=",this.state.view.done);
    if(this.state.view.done){
      this.setState({
        submitBtnText: "Login"
      });
    }
  },
    render: function() {
    return (
        <form className="form-horizontal col-xs-6" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        {this.state.view.value}
        <div className="form-group">
          <button className="btn btn-success pull-right">{this.state.submitBtnText}</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

check the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nagesh521/tst0fqjy/)

Thank you...

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work as I would expect it to, what's the problem?

Comment: At the end of component in array loaded into view, the iterator returns true but its not available when it is started rendering...when the last item in array loaded, based on the property done, i am changing the button text but its not happening here..please check the code

Comment: In your fiddle the button text changes

Comment: its changing but not end of the array..its changing when the index reaches out of array